# iOS Where is the main storyboard specified in project settings?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

Where is the main storyboard specified in project settings? Does Xcode just looks for a .storyboard and uses that one? I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Info.plist file. Just look for a .plist file in your project and you will find it. You also get a better display of the same information if you click your project (in the project outline on the left, top row), select your target and go to the General tab.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1):

It is stored in the Info.plist under `Main storyboard file base name` and `Main storyboard file base name (iPad)`